# why does 'puts continent_size(world,9,1)' return '0'

Tags: arrays, recursion

I am new to programming so I'm going through Chris Pine's "Learn to program, 2nd Edition" and came to the program below.  In his program in the book, world[8][2] = o, however, I changed it to M to further test his program.

When I made this change, the continent_size method returns 0 for **continent_size (world, 9, 1)** and I'm confused as to why.  Can anyone help?  Shouldn't this return 25??

```
o = 'water'
M = 'land'

world = [[o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o], 
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o], 
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o], 
         [o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o,M,o], 
         [o,o,o,M,o,M,M,o,o,o,o], 
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o], 
         [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,o], 
         [o,o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o], 
         [o,o,M,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o], 
         [o,M,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o], 
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o]]

def continent_size world, x, y          
    if world[x][y] != 'land'
    return 0
    end

  world[x][y] = 'counted land'
  size = 1

  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y-1) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x ,  y-1) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y-1) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y  ) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y  ) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y+1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x ,  y+1) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y+1)

  size

end

puts continent_size(world, 5, 5)
puts continent_size(world, 9, 1)

---------------------

25
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Before `continent_size(world, 9, 1)` is executed, the call to `continent_size(world, 5, 5)` changes the content of the array `world`. This is called [side-effects](/questions/tagged/side-effects). After `continent_size(world, 5, 5)` returns, your array `world` is modified as follows:

```
world = [[o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o],
         [o,o,o,C,o,o,o,o,o,M,o],
         [o,o,o,C,o,C,C,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,C,C,C,C,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,o],
         [o,o,o,C,C,o,C,C,C,o,o],
         [o,o,C,o,o,o,C,C,o,o,o],
         [o,C,o,o,o,C,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o]]
```

Where `C = 'counted land'`. Calling `continent_size(world, 9, 1)` after the array `world` is modified (as shown above) returns 0. Hence the output 25 0.